# Why does the code show prime and non-prime both answers?

Tags: javascript

**I am getting if and else both results from my JS Code even after using flags and break. What seems to be the possible reason?**

```
function myFunction(){
  let x = document.getElementById("int").value;
  const rootx = Math.sqrt(x);
  let textx = "";
  let isPrimeX = true;
  //checking the prime of x input
 for (let i = 2; i<=rootx; i++){
    if(x % i === 0 || x<=1 || x>2){
      textx += x + " is not a prime number"
      let isPrimeX = false;
      break;
    }
 }if(isPrimeX == true){
  textx += x + " is a Prime Number";
 }
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = textx;
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QQQ6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are redeclaring  `isPrimeX`

just remove `let` like this

```
function myFunction(){
  let x = document.getElementById("int").value;
  const rootx = Math.sqrt(x);
  let textx = "";
  let isPrimeX = true;
  //checking the prime of x input
 for (let i = 2; i<=rootx; i++){
    if(x % i === 0 || x<=1 || x>2){
      textx += x + " is not a prime number"
      isPrimeX = false;
      break;
    }
 }if(isPrimeX == true){
  textx += x + " is a Prime Number";
 }
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = textx;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring new `isPrimeX` within the loop using this  `let isPrimeX = false;`. It should be just `isPrimeX = false;`

Comment: OP is doing it correctly for `textx` so this is a typo type question.

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating your isPrimeX variable inside the `for` loop instead of just changing it's value. You can either remove the `let` inside the loop, or move `textx += x + " is a Prime Number";` into an `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

please try changing the declaration of isPrimeX again to assignment and see

```
function myFunction(){
  let x = document.getElementById("int").value;
  const rootx = Math.sqrt(x);
  let textx = "";
  let isPrimeX = true;
 //checking the prime of x input
  for (let i = 2; i<=rootx; i++){
    if(x % i === 0 || x<=1 || x>2){
     textx += x + " is not a prime number"

     //Change the let to assignment
     isPrimeX = false;

     break;
   }
  }if(isPrimeX == true){
  textx += x + " is a Prime Number";
  }
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = textx;
 }
```